# Replace the text in the column giving number

Tags: r

I have two variables `a` and `b` in my dataset:

```
 a                                           b
 fd648389-7ebb-4780-b9d1-4d4d5c8656ed        NA
 9b1a0172-056a-49e2-90e0-3b73874862b0        53c9f535-dda5-4e9b-9d0a-8f8f1dc8b1fd
```

I want to replace variable `b` with `a` whenever `b` has `NA`

output for `b`:

```
b
fd648389-7ebb-4780-b9d1-4d4d5c8656ed 
53c9f535-dda5-4e9b-9d0a-8f8f1dc8b1fd
```

I tried using it but `NA` is replaced with `1110` instead of `fd648389-7ebb-4780-b9d1-4d4d5c8656ed`. Iam not sure from where is `1110` coming from.

Comment: I tried using it but it replace   NA is replaced with 1110 instead of fd648389-7ebb-4780-b9d1-4d4d5c8656ed. Iam not sure from where is 1110 coming

Comment: That is highly probably because the columns have class factor. You can either read your data with using the parameter `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or convert the variables to character with `as.character`.

Comment: I tried converting it using as.character but it showing as NA

Comment: What is the the class of your `a` and `b` columns?

Comment: for a its factor and for b it shows as character

Comment: I change all the varaibles to character and tried using                                                                      b[i1] <- ifelse(b[i1] == "",a[i1],b[i1]). It ended in   NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Comment: In that case, changing `a` to character should work.